# How do I pass array to a function?

Tags: python

`tmp_rect_list` and `tmp_sheet` are the two variables that I want to pass to the function run_main(). `tmp_sheet` is done below but how do I do for `tmp_rect_list` as it is an array.

```
tmp_rect_list = [Rect(rcta[i], rcta[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(rcta), 2)]
tmp_sheet = Sheet(x,y)


def run_main():
    global tmp_sheet

    tmp_pops = init_population(tmp_sheet, tmp_rect_list, 100, rotate_prob = 0.5)

    best, avg_fit = best_individual(tmp_pops)
    print(best.fitness())
    print(avg_fit)
```

Comment: You want to pass `tmp_rect_list` to what function? `init_population`?

Comment: It does not matter array or not. Just pass it as any other variable. Maybe I don't understand something? Please clarify

Comment: Based on the code provided and its indentation, you don't need to pass `tmp_rect_list` and `tmp_sheet` to `run_main` for `run_main` to see the variables. Just call `run_main()`. If the posted code does not represent the one you have, then please update the code.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
//pass the array using C language
int *call(int arr[]);
int main(void)
{
    arr[] = {1,2,3};

    int *p = call(arr);
}
int *call(int arr[])
{
    /*Do some operation*/
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54806539/edit) your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.